# Entity Framework code first, custom, additonal fields in many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

In many to many relationship I want to maintain the sequence of the `Playlist` which is collection of the `Media` for a `Channel`. The sequence will be an int field from 0 to int max.

```
public class Channel
{
    public int ChannelId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Media> Playlist {get; set;}
}

public class Media
{
    public int MediaId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Channel> Channels {get; set;}
}
```

Using Entity Framework code first I want to design a many to many relationship between `Channel` and `Media` so that the `Channel` will have a `Playlist` items of type Media and also maintain the order sequence.

Entity Framework would add a table `ChannelMedias` for this relationship with following schema

```
ChannelMedias
-----------------------------
Channel_ChannelId   (int)
Media_MediaId       (int)
```

How can I maintain a sequence order like this:

```
ChannelMedias
------------------------------
Channel_ChannelId   (int)
Media_MediaId       (int)
MediaSequence       (int)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't supported by default entity framework. You need to define one more entity(ChanalMedia) to represent the relationship.

```
public class Channel
{
    public int ChannelId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ChanalMedia> ChanalMedias{get; set;}
}

public class ChanalMedia{
      public Channel Channel {get; set;}
      public Media Media {get; set;}
     //additional fields here..
}

public class Media
{
    public int MediaId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ChanalMedia> ChanalMedias{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like we have to use third entity and this cannot be done  by configuration/inheritance. Why `ICollection<ChanalMedia> ChanalMedias` is there in Media entity? How this association will be established and used?

Comment: It is to keep the many to many relationship via `ChanalMedia`

Comment: What would the fluent mapping look like for this. Thanks

Comment: I think no need to use Fluent Mapping here because the EF will create mapping by default since it follows the conventions.

Comment: Ok but if it did not follow convention. Its something I am trying to resolve at the moment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you are looking for a structure which allows for an ordering of the Media entities in the Playlist property. There are several ways of approaching this. One option is to have a Playlist class include the Media and add a PlaylistOrder property to it.

```
 public class Channel
    {
        public int ChannelId {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public ICollection<PlayListItem> Playlist {get; set;}
    }

    public class PlayListItem  
    {
        public int ID {get; set;}
        public int PlayListOrder {get; set;} 
        public Media Media {get; set;}
    }

    public class Media
    {
        public int MediaId {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Location {get; set;} 
    }
```

This would change the structure of your database a bit but would provide the functionality you need. It might be a bit more flexible however as you could then add more properties to PlayListItem such as TimesPlayed, LateDatePlayed etc

Comment: Thanks. I am also using a 3rd entity like PlayListItem as I couldn't do it with configuration. Why there is a need to have `ICollection<Channel> Channels` inside `Media`? How this association will be linked when I create a new PlayListItem?

Comment: Good point I hadnt noticed that, there's little benefit in having a collection of Channels in Media. Edited out. One other alternative is to have Media as a base class and have PlayListItem  inherit from it. This might make sense if you have a lot forms of media such video, audio etc...